# Assigning $_GET["id"] to a column id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having an issue with my code. I've tried different approaches but I have not found the solution. I am fetching a `$get_id` from my `golfers` table. I want to post the `$get_id` to a column called `courseid`. What my code is doing now is not posting to `courseid` and is posting the `$get_id` to my index `id`. I want to have the index `id` naturally auto increment numbers as well as post the `$get_id` to the `courseid` column. Please see my code below and let me know if you have a solution to my problem. Thank you.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "Submit")
{
    for ($count = 1; $count <= 9; $count++)
    {
        $fields[$count] = "";
        if (isset($_POST["field" . $count . ""]))
        {
            $fields[$count] = trim($_POST["field" . $count . ""]);
            //echo $fields[$count] . "<br />";
        }
    }

    $con = mysql_connect("", "", "");
    mysql_select_db("", $con);

    $coursename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['coursename']);
    $courseid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['courseid']);
    $hn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hn']);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);



    $insert = "INSERT INTO holes (`coursename` ,`courseid` ,`hn` ,`id` ) VALUES('$coursename' ,'$courseid' ,'$hn' ,'$id');";
    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

    $select = "SELECT `coursename` ,`courseid` ,`hn` ,`id` FROM `holes` WHERE id = '$courseid'";
    $result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
}
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $con = mysql_connect("", "", "");
    mysql_select_db("", $con);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
    $select = "SELECT * FROM `golfers` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
    $fields = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
    mysql_close($con);
}
else
{
    header("Location:board.php");
}
?>
</script>
<style ="text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></style><br><br><br>
</head>
<body>
<div
 style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 16px 20px 20px; width: 400px; background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216); text-align: center; float: left;">
<form action="" method="post";">
  <div
  style="margin: 8px auto auto; width: 300px; font-family: arial; text-align: left;"><br>
  <table style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
   <table
 style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Course Name:</td><td><input id="coursename" name="coursename" maxlength="50" style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="<?php echo $fields[coursename]; ?>">
                    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td style="width: 10%;">Hole #:</td><td>
              <select name="hn">
              <option></option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              </select>
              </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><input name="submit" value="Submit"
 class="submit" type="submit"></p>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see `$get_id` anywhere in your "code". I do see `$_GET["id"]` though.

Comment: That is what i meant. sorry I didn't clarify

Comment: `$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']); $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);` you have a conflict. Which should probably be `$get_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);`

Comment: So, were are we at? I've given you another issue above; have you dealt with it?

Comment: Ok I did that and it fixed the conflict of the index `id` but I am still not having the `get_id` posting as the `courseid`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to tell me how you're getting `get_id` from. You haven't told me that yet, nor have you updated your question to reflect that change in your code. *However*, you may need to set a hidden field in your form called `<input type="hidden" name="get_id" value="<?php echo $get_id; ?>` type of thing.

Comment: I think I got it! Thanks to your tips! I just changed the ` $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);` to ` $courseid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);` and I added the hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="course" value="<?php echo $courseid; ?>`